# functions sound/delay/nosound in dos.h for c/c++

Tags: c++, c, winapi, codeblocks

How can I get a version of language C/C++(downloaded??) where the functions sound, nosound, delay are present in the library DOS.H? 
For example it doesn't exist in the version c/c++ on code::blocks. What have I to do in order to use/find the functions sound/nosound/delay?
thank you for your help !

Comment: You want these functions to work on Windows or you just need a cross-compiler to create DOS binaries ?

Comment: You'll have to break into a museum.  Like the Borland museum: http://edn.embarcadero.com/museum.  Won't work on *nix and won't work on a 64-bit operating system without an emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows programs you may use win32 functions:

- [`Sleep()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as a replacement for `delay()`
- [`Beep()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as a replacement for a combination of `sound()` + `delay()` + `nosound()`.

Answer (score 4):

download (sigh) a copy of TurboC/TurboC++.

Comment: Thanks your for the answer. How can I use DJGPP 16 bit version? which copy of turboC/turboC++ ?(on each copy of c, I don't find the functions sound in the library dos.h). What do you mean with Watson?

Comment: turboC/C++ 3.0 is the last turboC i have ever seen. @Den's

Comment: [16-bit DJGPP is very raw and has been that way for years](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/16bit/gcc/). I'd not recommend using it. The normal, 32-bit DJGPP is much better. However, given that Windows after XP has extremely limited support for DOS programs in 32-bit Windows and no support whatsoever in 64-bit versions of Windows, I'd recommend against 32-bit DJGPP as well.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze recommending me to remove that option?

Comment: It's up to you. I'm just letting you and the OP know that there are issues with DOS programs in Windows and with Turbo C/C++ 3.xx- and DJGPP, all of which are DOS programs as well.

Comment: He specifically wanted delay(), sound() and nosound() functions.

Comment: With a old version, i recognize it is possible to use the functions, but it isn't practical/easy, I didn't know that the function beep() could replace the "old" functions... so I try it and it is running on the news IDEs. Many thanks guys !!

Answer (score 0):

if u r having above win 7,, Download borland Turbo c++ using dos box
to listen to a beep for 500 miliseconds, use the following code,

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
void main()
{clrscr();  //for clearing the screen...
int x;
x=1000;         // here 1000 is the frequency of the sound 
sound(x);       //u can directly write integer in the place of x
delay(500);
nosound();      //it is necessary to close the sound or u will keep on hearing

getch();        // to wait at the end of program
}
```