# sound() and nosound() function of C in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, audio

Can someone tell how I can use sound() and nosound() function of C in Linux? I could use it in Windows by including dos.h header file but I'm on Linux so I cannot use dos.h there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001650/functions-sound-delay-nosound-in-dos-h-for-c-c

Comment: @Brandin the question is not a duplicate. The question in your link talks nothing about linux.

Comment: @bubble possible duplicate means it could be a duplicate, or depending on interpretation, not a duplicate - OP can infer from the linked answer that one must find an os-specific solution or cross-platform solution

Comment: @Brandin suggesting a question as possible duplicate generally leads to closure of further discussion on it. We don't want this thing to happen here. None of the answers given for the linked question seems to apply to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there seems to be no simple solution. You can define a beep function something like

```
/* beep.c - for Linux and DOS/Windows */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifdef __DJGPP__
#include <dos.h>
#include <pc.h>
#endif
#define ESC 27

void beep (int frequency, int duration)
{
#ifdef __DJGPP__
  sound (frequency);
  delay (duration);
  nosound ();
#else  /* Linux */
  FILE *tty;
  if ( NULL == (tty = fopen ("/dev/console", "w")) ) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Cannot write to /dev/console!\n" );
    exit (1);
  }
  fprintf(tty, "%c[10;%d]%c[11;%d]\a", ESC, frequency, ESC, duration);
#endif
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int frequency, duration;
  if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Usage: beep <frequency> <duration>\n" );
    exit (1);
  }
  frequency = atoi (argv [1]);
  duration = atoi (argv [2]);
  beep (frequency, duration);
  return (0);
}

/* end of beep.c */
```

There is no dos.h equivalent in linux. You need to explore from what is available in linux

Check [here](http://abcplus.sourceforge.net/beep.c)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a debian based distro, you could install beep package:

`sudo apt-get install beep`

now you could call the beep command from your C/C++ code in Linux like this:

`#include stdlib.h>
int main(void){
     system(beep);
}`