# Does <dos.h> header file work in codeblocks?

Tags: c, delay, codeblocks, timedelay

The delay function of `dos.h` header file does not work in codeblocks. It shows that delay function is undeclared.
  the following link contains the program below.
  [link](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/dos.h/delay)

```
int main  ()
{ 
printf     (  "  This c program will exit in 10 seconds.\n");         
delay(10000);                         
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably need to add the corresponding library (whatever it is) to your project's link settings.

Comment: It should also complain about `printf`. You need `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <dos.h>`. Please include the exact error message in your question. BTW, a quick Google search turned up a very similar program on [this web page](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/dos.h/delay); I've lost track of the number of serious errors on that page.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: If it says it's *undeclared* (rather than undefined), then it's probably not a linker error. We need to see the exact error message. The lack of `#include <dos.h>` is also notable.

Comment: It can be done by turbo c. But i want it to do by code blocks.i tried to add the library also though dos.h is already available in codeblocks

Comment: AFAIK, codeblocks is only the IDE. The disponibility of headers and libraries depend on the underlying system and compiler ... and on the capacity of the programmer to correctly add include lines in source and libraries in project configuration !

Comment: possible duplicate of [functions sound/delay/nosound in dos.h for c/c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001650/functions-sound-delay-nosound-in-dos-h-for-c-c)

Comment: The header file probably "works" fine (insofar a header file can work). `delay`, however, is not a standard C function.

Comment: What happens when you add `#include <dos.h>` to the top of your source file?

Comment: same error prevails inspite of adding <dos.h> to the top

Comment: can anyone suggest me an IDE other than codeblocks and turbo c to compile this type of programs.i guess changing the compiler in codeblocks may not be the correct solution.maybe IDE is the case.as in case of graphics.h header file also does not response in codeblocks.i want to know the cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also having same problem &  I used this function

```
 #include <time.h>
 void delay(int milliseconds)
 {
   long pause;
   clock_t now,then;

   pause = milliseconds*(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
   now = then = clock();
   while( (now-then) < pause )
     now = clock();
 }
```

#### edited :

As commented, this does make system busy. I have fund better way to do it, and works for CodeBlocks.

```
#include <windows.h>
 .
 .
 .
 Sleep(100); //sleep for 0.1 second
 .
```

Comment: `delay()` or equivalent means your process will be idle until the delay expires. A busy loop will needlessly cause your process to consume CPU time continuously. The value returned by `clock()` represents CPU time, not real time. Finally, on some systems the value returned by `clock()` wraps around in less than an hour.

Comment: even this doesn't work , sleep shows the same error as delay, even i include the windows.h header file.

Comment: @Tilak raj -->`Sleep()' where s is capital, should work on windows platform if you are using mingw compiler.

Answer (score 0):

i think it only works on turbo c. 
It is a  Borland specific and works in turbo c compiler.

[see link](http://www.billioncodes.com/en/c/tutorials/719-dos-h-header-file-in-c-programming-language)