# How can I use sound and nosound function in code blocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

I have used sound and no sound function in turbo C++, but I cannot get it to work in code blocks compiler. 
Program:

```
 int main() 
 {
     sound();
     delay();
     nosound();
     return 0;
 }
```

I have added definition for delay and it's working in other programs. 
When I am compiling this code I am getting error as ::undefined reference to sound and no sound.

How can I make this work?  Or is there a different solution I should use?

Comment: What is that `Int`? That won't even compile. FYI, Turbo C has their own libraries/headers for the sound functionality.

Comment: The `sound()` functions were in `dos.h`, which is Turbo-C++ specific. Sadly, those functions simply don't exist in Code::Blocks. Slightly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001650/functions-sound-delay-nosound-in-dos-h-for-c-c

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use "Beep" function which is in windows.h header file.
   In Beep function you have to give 2 parameters , first is for frequency and       second is duration in milliseconds.
2. You can '\a' which gives alert sound, '\a' should be placed in printf.

Answer (score -1):

I'm doing this right now! But i'm using C, dunno if for C++ is the same.

The only thing i know is that you have to include the library dos.h to make it work.

the function is Beep(soundfrequency,delay);
give it a try with Beep(2000,2000);

Good luck :)